# Can't find html file in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I am looking for editing one of my website in wordpress. But the backend of page editing is empty and no any page builders. I also looked for files in theme editor. But can't find html file. Please help me.

Comment: What page is that ? can you put the link here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `HTML` file in Backend of `Wordpress`. All `HTML` files render by `wordpress` from `.php` files.

All you need is to go to your current `Theme` directory (`wp-content/themes/your-theme-name`) and edit `.php` file of your specific page.